# Why is there a B in my flair?

Tags: bug, status-completed, flair

> **This was originally noticed and fixed back around the beginning of July. As of August 1, this problem seems to have returned.**
>
> New bug report is here: [Single site SE flair not displaying the correct icon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191513/single-site-se-flair-not-displaying-the-correct-icon)

I just happened to notice that my SO flair has some sort of a `B` icon right before my username (instead of the expected site icon)

Snapshot of the unknown icon:

> [image: My flair with an unknown icon]

My current (live) flair for monitoring:
[image: profile for jcsanyi at Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers]

It currently showing up like this for all users on all sites, but not on Combined or Meta flairs. For example Jon Skeet flair on programmers:

> [image]

Live flair:
[image]

Comment: B for brilliant.

Comment: Actually - that's where the site icon is supposed to go, right?

Comment: Yeah. That's the Bicycles icon in the old beta theme (Sketchy)

Comment: Now that's a flattering comparison - and thanks to the icon, you can't even see that they're different sites. :)

Comment: Cheers, we are all equal in the eyes of the Flair! :-P

Comment: +1 I was busy writing the same question...

Comment: Should we start a pool on who's responsible? Was it "The Slash"?

Comment: A pool? That's so last century @jcsanyi. We have the wheel of blame http://jsfiddle.net/yijiang/AYPpF/24/embedded/result/

Comment: @jcsanyi Not exactly, but very close.

Comment: What site are you on where Skeet only has 2.5 k?

Comment: @animuson In cases like this please don't remove the status-completed tag. If the bug (or one that looks similar) reappears, it should get a new bug report.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was another fallout from the beginning SSL move. Fixed now.

Since flair is heavily cached, this won't be autocorrected until the wrongly rendered image is dropped from the cache, which can take up to 24 hours. And I don't want to wipe the full cache all at once, because that may become a bit overwhelming for our servers. But so you don't have to wait until then, I've added a temporary way for users to clear the cached image:

If you prepend `?nocache=true` to the flair image URL, it will regenerate the correct flair. This only works on your own flair, and it will only work once, so don't bother building a script to give you real-time updating flair :)

Sorry about that bug.

Comment: I used the `nocache` flag to refresh my flair this morning, and it seemed to work - but checking again a couple hours later, it looks like it's back to the `B` icon again.

Comment: It looks like the `nocache` flag didn't work as expected - but once the cache actually expired properly, everything's back to normal.

Comment: It's back in full B-force.

Comment: How do we deal with recurring bugs like this? Is it possible to remove the status-completed tag? or does that require a moderator/developer?

Comment: @jcsanyi that's a new meta question. It isn't possible anyway, I tried.

Comment: @jcsanyi but maybe we could add a new tag `status-reopened`?

Comment: @jcsanyi I guess someone with 500 rep can do that... (but who?)

Comment: @jcsanyi When the bug was clearly fixed previously and unless the bug reappears after a very short time (in other words: the fix wasn't quite right), post a new bug report.

Comment: @balpha the new report is here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191513/single-site-se-flair-not-displaying-the-correct-icon

Comment: @balpha Got it. Thanks.