# Single site SE flair not displaying the correct icon

Tags: bug, status-completed, flair

I'm having reports from users of my community that the peoples profile flairs are displaying the old beta icon instead of the correct one for their community.

Here is what I see:

[image: That's-a-me!]

The combined flair seems to be unaffected.

Even after clearing my browser cache, I see this on Area 51:

[image: What I see]

It seems to be affecting Beta and Graduated sites, but not Meta.SO for some reason:

[image: Why not?]

Comment: It's not just A51. I checked my flair on several sites and it was wrong on all but MSO.

Comment: Bug that was fixed returned.

Comment: I'm seeing this at Server Fault as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was my bug.  I implemented support for protocol/scheme relative URLs for all of our static content yesterday, e.g. `//cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js`.  We also support just plain `/content` for here on meta and the check for that difference was a "starts with `/`"...that's not good anymore, eh?

Unfortunately we cache the flair icons we generate with, so after building these changes *then* changing the values the bug wasn't exposed until another build.  Sorry about that.

This is now fixed, but it looks like cache breakers on all our static content aren't appending...going to fix that in just a moment.